# sendmail not working in crontab

Tags: shell, unix, cron, sendmail

I am facing issue when I try to execute my script from crontab but when I try to execute manually, it works perfectly fine.

**Crontab File**

```
54 * * * * /opt/SP/home/osbadm/scripts/tmp1.sh 2>&1
```

**Sendmail function**

```
SUBJECT="test"
TO="to@gmail.com" (
echo "TO: $TO"
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
cat $EXTRACT_CST_HTML
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f from@gmail.com $TO
```

Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Does the script have the execute bit set. It should also begin with `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: Can't see Cron logs , don't have access to see them. Not receiving email. Any other way to debug ?

Comment: Yes. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info for many tips on how to debug failing cron jobs, including creating an error log

Comment: Thanks Man ! issue resolved, Barmar's answer helped

Comment: You should also learn to use shellcheck.net to validate your scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a variable assignment before the `(` that starts a subshell. If you'd pasted your script into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) it would have told you:

> SC1036: '(' is invalid here. Did you forget to escape it?

Also, even if you could, it would only set the variable inside the subprocess's environment, it wouldn't be visible when processing the arguments to `sendmail`. So put that assignment on its own line. Also, a here-doc is an easier way to pass multiple lines of input to `sendmail`.

```
TO="to@gmail.com"
(
echo "TO: $TO"
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
cat $EXTRACT_CST_HTML
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f from@gmail.com $TO
```